# Insert a div in specific position - php, joomla

Tags: php, joomla

The issue is the following. This code loads items and displays them on the page. Now I want to place a specific div tag after the first item in the second position and only on the start page and only once. I have solved the home page problem. But unfortunately I can't get it to appear once at the second position. How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Original Code:
`

```
  <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    $s = 0;
                    $t = count($items);
                    foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                        <?php if ($i % $cols == 0): /* start new row */ ?>
                            <div class="row-articles equal-height">
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-<?php echo $col_width ?> magazine-item">
                            <?php echo JATemplateHelper::render($item, 'joomla.content.intro', array('item' => $item, 'params' => $aparams)); ?>
                           
                         
                        </div>
                        <?php if (++$i % $cols == 0 || $i == $t): /* close row */ ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

`

Code with specific div tag:
`

```
  <?php
                    $i = 0;
                    $s = 0;
                    $t = count($items);
                    foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                        <?php if ($i % $cols == 0): /* start new row */ ?>
                            <div class="row-articles equal-height">
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-<?php echo $col_width ?> magazine-item">
                            <?php echo JATemplateHelper::render($item, 'joomla.content.intro', array('item' => $item, 'params' => $aparams)); ?>
                            <?php
                            $app = JFactory::getApplication();
                            $menu = $app->getMenu();
                            if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
                                echo '<div id="nativendo-homepage-' . ++$s . '"></div>' ;}?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if (++$i % $cols == 0 || $i == $t): /* close row */ ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

`

what i tried:

`

```
$i = 0;
                    $s = 0;
                    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
                    $menu = $app->getMenu();
                    $t = count($items);
                    foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                        <?php if ($i % $cols == 0): /* start new row */ ?>
                            <div class="row-articles equal-height">
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-<?php echo $col_width ?> magazine-item">
                            <?php echo JATemplateHelper::render($item, 'joomla.content.intro', array('item' => $item, 'params' => $aparams));?>
                        </div>
                        
                      <?php
                            $k = count(array($item));
                            if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault() && $i == 2):
                                echo '<div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-' . $col_width . ' magazine-item"><div id="nativendo-homepage-' . ++$s . $k . '"></div></div>'  ; endif ?>
              
                        <?php if (++$i % $cols == 0 || $i == $t): /* close row */ ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are welcome to ask Joomla-related questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. @djdlife